# Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I've followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0) line by line. It's teaches how to generate a blazor wasm hosted application with all the code to authenticate with Azure B2C. All I had to do was to replace place the correct values in the right places.

`dotnet new blazorwasm -au IndividualB2C --aad-b2c-instance "{AAD B2C INSTANCE}" --api-client-id "{SERVER API APP CLIENT ID}" --app-id-uri "{SERVER API APP ID URI}" --client-id "{CLIENT APP CLIENT ID}" --default-scope "{DEFAULT SCOPE}" --domain "{TENANT DOMAIN}" -ho -o {APP NAME} -ssp "{SIGN UP OR SIGN IN POLICY}"`

Unfortunately, when I run it I get this error:

[image]

It's hard to tell where the problem is coming from. I googled the error but can't find any documentation on the issue.

Thanks for helping.

## Edit

Here's the script that I use to create the Blazor app

`dotnet new blazorwasm -au IndividualB2C --aad-b2c-instance "testb2c.onmicrosoft.com" --api-client-id "3b113bda-55d5-47eb-9d8c-5e44375f1341" --app-id-uri "https://testb2c.onmicrosoft.com/testapi" --client-id "3b9fd635-a87f-4899-ad04-9a73fc6f4e21" --default-scope "api.read" --domain "testb2c.onmicrosoft.com" -ho -o BlazorCmdLine -ssp "B2C_1_SignUpIn"`

Comment: It is a guess and not an answer. Maybe you have some "invalid chars" like spaces in your variables? And when the authentications service tries to construct the redirect URL???  for the request, it produces the error?

Comment: Your url should look like this:  `https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{SERVER API APP ID URI}/scope name`.

Comment: @CarlZhao I just posted my script in the question. Which part of the script should be the way you're describing in your comment?

Comment: What will happen if you run `dotnet new blazorwasm -au IndividualB2C -ho -o BlazorCmdLine`?

Comment: @AllenWu, running this command generated only placeholders, which allow to see exactly what was the expectation. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 2 real problems related to the lack of attention.

1. I used the same value `testb2c.onmicrosoft.com` for both the {AAD B2C INSTANCE} and the {TENANT DOMAIN}.

- `{AAD B2C INSTANCE} Instance` should be  `https://testb2c.b2clogin.com/`
- `{TENANT DOMAIN} domain` should be `testb2c.onmicrosoft.com`

2. I forgot to add a **forward slash** at the end of the {AAD B2C INSTANCE} Instance. So I was getting `"Authority": "testb2c.onmicrosoft.comtestb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpIn"`,

Thank you, @just the benno, @Carl Zhao, and @Allen Wu

Comment: You forgot # 2.  Ha ha ha.  Just kidding, man.  This had me for over an hour and I would never have guessed.  Thanks!

Comment: The Authority should also start with 'https://'

Comment: I receive the exact same error, I think I set an incorrect signup/signin policy

Answer (score 5):

To anyone who finds themselves in this situation - instead of checking your values and running the command again, open up the appsettings.json file and check the "AzureAdB2C.Authority" value.  It should be a valid URL in the format: "{AAD B2C INSTANCE}/{TENANT DOMAIN}/{SIGN UP OR SIGN IN POLICY}"

Example:
"https://testb2c.b2clogin.com/testb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn"

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure appSettings.json file is included when building/running your solution.

appSettings.json will contain configuration values of your Azure AD B2C similar to the following:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://contoso.b2clogin.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1",
    "ClientId": "4369008b-21fa-427c-abaa-9b53bf58e538",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
}
```

Double-click your project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio to open the .csproj file.

In my case the .csproj file contained an ItemGroup saying to never include appSettings.json during debugging or running of the app:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="appSettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Never" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I commented the entire item group and saved the .csproj, ran the app and I could successfully authenticate.